# Define the order of classes and jars of a webapp in play2

Tags: dependency-management, playframework-2.0

I'm trying play2, and write a simple project.

I found a bug in a 3rd-party jar in my project, so I get the source and modify it, place it in the `app/` directory of the project.

When I use `play test`, all the tests passed. But when I `play run` it as a web app, it reports errors.

Seems that `play test` found and used the correct(modified) source, but `play run` used incorrect original class. In order to let `play run` work correct, I have to modify the original jar(delete that buggy class), to make sure there is only my modified class.

But this is boring, so I wonder if there is a way to set the orders of classes and jars when running `play run`, e.g. let it use my sources first, then 3rd-party jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand you have the same code twice: in a *jar* file and in your application path. By same code I mean the same class name in the same package.

If that's the case, this is not very well supported in the JVM. I'm sure that you could find some workaround via reflection or playing with the classloader, but to be honest, it's much simpler to just modify the original *jar* with the patch.

In fact it may be simpler to send the fix to the provider of the 3rd party *jar* and ask them to rebuild, so other people benefit from your fix. If that's not possible, just edit the *jar*.